# What is the proper way of saying "internship period"?

Tags: word-request, vocabulary, collocations

I don't even know how to put this... I got accepted to a programming job in a small firm but technically I haven't been accepted yet. They are evaluating my skills and abilities to see if I am capable to do the job and if they like it then they will accept me. And I was wondering the proper word/colloquialism in English for this particular period of time. I thought it was *internship period*, but it is not really an internship. Maybe *evaluation period*, *assessment period* ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those might work. I imagine the usage can vary by company. But the common one I know is "probation", or "probationary period" (my emphasis):

> In a workplace setting, [probation (or probationary period)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probation_(workplace)) is a status given to new employees of a company or business. It is widely termed as the Probation Period of an employee. This status allows a supervisor or other company manager to evaluate closely the progress and skills of the newly hired worker, determine appropriate assignments, and monitor other aspects of the employee such as honesty, reliability, and interactions with co-workers, supervisors or customers.
>
> [...]
>
> **The probationary period also allows an employer to terminate an employee who is not doing well at their job or is otherwise deemed not suitable for a particular position or any position.** Whether or not this empowers employers to abuse their employees by, without warning, terminating their contract before the probation period has ended is open for debate.
>   (Wikipedia)

Answer (score 0):

You're probably thinking of **probation** or a **probationary period**.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probation_(workplace)):

> In a workplace setting, probation (or probationary period) is a status given to new employees of a company or business. It is widely termed as the Probation Period of an employee. This status allows a supervisor or other company manager to evaluate closely the progress and skills of the newly hired worker, determine appropriate assignments, and monitor other aspects of the employee such as honesty, reliability, and interactions with co-workers, supervisors or customers.

Although it varies from company to company, it's common for a probationary period to be around three months, and it's also common for either the employee or the employer to be able to sever the relationship without any penalty. (Or at least that's what the theory is, I haven't actually heard of this being exercised in practice.)